# Is there an ability in lua to check if a trinket is on cooldown and if not use it

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

Is there an ability in Lua to use an item like a trinket and check if it is on cooldown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the WoW API function `GetItemCooldown(itemID)`. To obtain the item ID you'd use the `GetInventoryItemID("unit", InventorySlotId)` function:

```lua
local itemID = GetInventoryItemID("player", 13) -- 13 for trinket1, 14 for trinket2
local start, duration, enable = GetItemCooldown(itemID)
if enable == 1 and duration == 0 then
  -- You can use the item
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Since there is an API function call is there also an equivalent Macro?

Comment: I'm not familiar with those sorry :/ I suppose you could use the `/script` macro in any case. `/script local itemID = GetInventoryItemID("player", 13); local start, duration, enable = GetItemCooldown(itemID); if enable == 1 and duration == 0 then print('Trinket can be used') end`?

Comment: What I understood was that while you can print that the trinket is ready for use you cannot actually use the trinket programmatically.  This is to prevent everything being automatic I would be assume.  Blizzards anti botting attitude?

Comment: That has to do with the [Protection](https://wowwiki.fandom.com/wiki/Category:World_of_Warcraft_API/Protected_Functions) of the function that you're calling. When it's triggered by a manual keystroke or mouseclick you can actually run quite extensive macros.

Comment: More checking says that instead of print I cannot do UseInventoryItem(13);.  Which makes sense.